# Angular2 HTTP put add authorization header

Tags: angular, http-status-code-401, http-put

I am trying to use http put in Angular. My code looks like this:

```
const url ='this is my url';
const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'this is my token'});
return this.http.put(url, {headers: headers}).toPromise().then......
```

But I keep getting 401 Unauthorized as request status code.
I tried to copy my request from Chrome Network tab to Postman, and I noticed that the authorization header was added to the request body, not to the headers.

[image]

Is this normal?

If I add manually in Postman the authorization header as a header the request works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs https://angular.io/api/http/Http

**Http.put** method signature is:

```
put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

So, your second parameter should be the data/body, not the options.

Try:

```
return this.http.put(url, {}, {headers: headers}).toPromise().then......
```

Comment: This is for AngularJS which is a completely different framework to Angular +2 ;)

Comment: Thanks ! Works now.

Comment: @ZiedKoubaa glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

When you do a `PUT` request you need to provide a body, because right now you are passing the `headers` as the body in your request. So your request would be something like

`this.http.put(url, body, headers)`

Comment: Thanks ! Works now.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

When I use httpclient in angular2+ framework, I usually use like this :

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

Did you check `Content-Type` in headers?

if you want to add set auth header in service layer, when you call httpClient, you can use Http interceptor ( https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/ )